# Required field validator is not showing error validation message

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation

Data validation is happening but not displaying error message.

on click of submit button it doesn't show error message.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="GroupNameDropDown" 
    SetFocusOnError="True"
    InitialValue="0"
    ValidationGroup="BatchTranEntry">
    <div 
        id="GroupNameDropDownError" 
        class="errorImage" 
        runat="server" style="position:absolute" ></div>
    <uc1:ErrorTip 
        ID="ErrorTip8" 
        runat="server"
        Message="Group Name is a required Field"
        PopUpPosition="Right"
        TargetControl="GroupNameDropDownError"
        Title="Group Name"
        Width="225px" />
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: put `ValidationGroup="BatchTranEntry"` on button property if you are using `<asp:Button>` Control.

Comment: Added Validation Group in <asp:Button> tag but its not helpful.
Is there any other work around.